# Why do I need to duplicate my Prolog predicates in order to make my program work?

Tags: prolog, dcg

I am using SICStus Prolog 4.0.8 to write a program that parses a sentence in English and returns the syntactic tree, as well as a yes/no on whether the sentence is correct according to the programmed grammar. Here is an example (sentence is *Larry and Carol meet their older neighbors Paul and Lillian*):

```
s(s(N, V)) --> np(N), vp(V).
np(np1(N1, C, N2)) --> pn(N1), conj(C), pn(N2).
np(np2(D, A, N)) --> det(D), adj(A), cn(N).
app(app(N1, N2)) --> np2(N1), np1(N2).
vp(vp1(V, A)) --> tv(V), app(A).
```

If I run the code like this, it complains that np2/3 is not defined, but if I put the numbers before the brackets, then it complains np/3 is not defined. My only solution is to put both predicates in, like this:

```
s(s(N, V)) --> np(N), vp(V).
np(np1(N1, C, N2)) --> pn(N1), conj(C), pn(N2).
np(np2(D, A, N)) --> det(D), adj(A), cn(N).
app(app(N1, N2)) --> np2(N1), np1(N2).
vp(vp1(V, A)) --> tv(V), app(A).
np1(np1(N1, C, N2)) --> pn(N1), conj(C), pn(N2).
np2(np2(D, A, N)) --> det(D), adj(A), cn(N).
vp1(vp1(V, A)) --> tv(V), app(A).
```

Then it compiles and executes successfully. What's the cause of this behavior?

Comment: The number after the name of the predicate in the error message and for that matter any place else with that notation, the number is not part of the name but an indicator of the number of arguments for that predicate. See: [Concepts](https://www.metalevel.at/prolog/concepts)

Comment: I understand that; I am talking about the numbers to the left of the slash; those that I wrote myself. SICStus complains if I don't define both np(N) and np1(N) and so on.

Comment: Then where did you get this code from? As I often say to new users here, if the [duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) don't know it we don't know it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the **first version** of your code, the clause

```
np(np1(N1, C, N2)) --> pn(N1), conj(C), pn(N2).
```

defines the predicate `np/3` (and calls the predicate `pn/3`). However, the clause

```
app(app(N1, N2)) --> np2(N1), np1(N2).
```

calls predicates `np2/3` and `np1/3`, which are not defined. That's the cause of the  runtime error.

In the **second version** of your code, the predicates `np2/3` and `np1/3` are also defined and, therefore, there is no error.

**What's the problem?** I think you are confusing `np/3` and `pn/3` (which are *predicates*) with `np1/3` and `np2/3` (which are *terms* representing syntax tree nodes).

```
np( np1(N1, C, N2) ) --> pn(N1), conj(C), pn(N2).
^    ^                   ^
|    |                   |
|    |                   +--- predicate being called (must be defined)
|    |
|    +----------------------- term representing a syntax tree node (this is not a predicate) 
|
+---------------------------- predicate being defined
```

Comment: It is unfortunate, though maybe convenient for some who understand what's going on, that some names like `s` and `app` are used with both meanings.

Comment: @aschepler That's true!

Comment: I understood most of the answer, except this part: "app(app(N1, N2)) --> np2(N1), np1(N2).
calls predicates np2/3 and np1/3, which are not defined." Doesn't it call np2/1 and np1/1?

Comment: @Kingfisher In fact, the arguments representing the input and output lists are not written explicitly in DCG notation but they are added when the rule is translated into an ordinary Prolog clause. For example, a DCG rule `terminal(terminal_node(X)) --> [X].` can be translated into `terminal(terminal_node(X), [X|A], A).` (notice that the argument `[X|A]` is the input list and the argument `A`  is the output list). Thus, we can refer to the predicate defined by this rule as `terminal//1` (before translation) or `terminal/3` (after translation).